# Apache NiFi Funnel vs Multiple Connections to the Same Processor

Tags: apache-nifi

IN NiFi what's the real difference between using Funnel to combine multiple connections into a single connection versus just making multiple connections directly to the target processor.

Is there any real difference (performance, etc..)? Didn't find any explanation in docs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, it is beneficial as an organisational tool.

Let's say you have 10 GenerateFlowFile processors connected to an UpdateAttribute processor. Now, you want to replace the UpdateAttribute with SplitText.

Without a funnel, you need to move the connections one by one over to the new SplitText.

With a funnel, you simply move the funnel's output to the new SplitText and don't touch the original 10 connections.

Other than this, a funnel has it's own queue. Thus, 10 queues connected to one funnel results in one combined queue. This can be useful if you want to centralise the backpressure for each of the connected processor, or perhaps apply some ordering to the combined queue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
I'm more interested about performance - how does processor (for example with just 1 concurrent task set) handles multiple connection queues - does it read then in sequential/random order, should I increase number of concurrent tasks if there are multiple connection queues.

Comment: Great answer, although i am not sure if this answered your performance question. From my experience, 10 concurrent tasks in 10 queues to 10 concurrent tasks in a single queue may have a bit of delay. May be, not that visible enough. I am watching this space for any more answers, comments or responses.